# How does an enhancement bonus to base speed affect a creature with no land speed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, polymorph

In Pathfinder, what is the effect of an enhancement bonus to land speed for a creature that has no specified land speed?

For example, a druid is under the effects of both [*Longstrider*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/longstrider/) and a polymorph. They have Wild Shaped into a form with no listed base land speed (such as a [giant squid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/squid/giant-squid/)). Yet the *Longstrider* provides a +10 ft enhancement bonus to base speed (i.e., land speed).

(I realize that *Haste* would not apply, because it limits the new speed to 2x the natural base speed. But there are other sources of these bonuses, such as [from wondrous items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-of-striding-and-springing/).)

**With the enhancement bonus, what is the creature's calculated base land speed?**

The result is likely one of the following:

- A) An unspecified land speed would count as 0 ft speed. Then, increase it by the enhancement bonus, yielding a new land speed equal to the enhancement bonus.
- B) Or, they still don't have a land speed, because there is nothing to enhance.

Comment: In the squid example I assume their water speed would be considered their base speed, would it not?

Comment: @RobRose Not in the examples I mentioned. Longstrider specifically does not affect non-land movement speeds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A creature needs *some* kind of land speed to benefit from bonuses to its land speed

This 2012 [post](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5ldw0&page=3?The-FAQ-That-Time-Forgot#141) on a vaguely similar topic has *Pathfinder* designer Jason Bulhman's saying that, essentially, *You can't add something to nothing*. That is, the designer makes a distinction between something having a value of *0* and a value of *no value*. Having a land speed of even 0 ft. is different from having *no* land speed *at all*.<sup>1</sup>

Thus a [giant squid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/squid/giant-squid) (or a druid that's used the supernatural ability wild shape to assume the form of a giant squid) that possesses no listed land speed can't benefit from the spell [*longstrider*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/longstrider) at all. Instead, the giant squid will first need an effect like the spell [*fins to feet*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fins-to-feet/) to *gain* a land speed at which point it can benefit from spells and effects like *longstrider*.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>**1**</sup> I know of no creature with a land speed of 0 ft., but *Pathfinder* is pretty vast, so I'm hedging. The [shrieker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants/shrieker/), however, for example, *does* have a land speed of only 5 ft. therefore is able to benefit from the *longstrider* spell just fine.
<sup>**2**</sup> Both the [octopus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/octopus) and [giant octopus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/octopus/octopus-giant/) do possess land speeds. Consider those forms instead for your high-speed land-based tentacled needs.